# Mersenne semiprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers, semiprimes

> Is it known does the set of Mersenne numbers contain an infinite number of semiprimes?

By the same procedure as with primes if $n=abc$ with $a,b,c>1$ is composite number then $2^{abc}-1$ is divisible by $2^a-1$ and $2^b-1$ and $2^c-1$, so for $2^n-1$ to be a semiprime we must have $n=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes and $2^p-1$ and $2^q-1$ are simulatenously primes or $n=p$, a prime.

Even if a made a mistake somewhere in description of my thoughts about the question, is this question settled anywhere?

Comment: AFAIK it is an open question.  You might look at [OEIS sequence A085724 ](https://oeis.org/A085724) and references there.

Comment: $(2^p-1)(2^q-1)=2^{p+q}-2^p-2^q+1<2^n$ so it actually takes $(p=q)\otimes (n=p=q)$ But it's hard to settle, as the Fermat quotient in the last case must be of form: $$2ijp+i+j$$ resembling the Sieve of Sundaram. However $i,j$ can't be that form for other values. In the other case, I can't figure it out.