# Are Semiprimes in the Mersenne Sequence Bound (Eventually) to Occur at Terms of Prime Index?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, mersenne-numbers, semiprimes

Related to a question posed a year and a half ago on the site,

[Mersenne semiprimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582395/mersenne-semiprimes)

I would now like to ask, that in the sequence of Mersenne numbers, does there exist a bound on the indices, say $K$, for which any term of the Mersenne sequence that happens to be a semiprime beyond $K$ must be a term of prime index?

Comment: what has been tried ...

Comment: it's equivalent to is there only a finite number of prime square exponents that satisfy it. probably is published just not in a place most looks. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematics_journals

Comment: When are reunpits in base 2^n prime ?